# Prime ideal in $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: ring-theory

Let $I$ be a prime ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, then $I\cap \mathbb{Z}$ is a prime ideal in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Is it possible to use the second isomorphism theorem to prove this?

$\mathbb{Z}/(I\cap\mathbb{Z})\cong (\mathbb{Z}+I)/I$

How do I show that $(\mathbb{Z}+I)/I$ is an integral domain?

Or is there any easier way to do it? Thanks !

Comment: It might be easier to work directly from the definition. (An ideal $\mathfrak p \subset R$ is prime iff, given $a, b \in R$ such that $ab \in \mathfrak p$, either $a \in \mathfrak p$ or $b \in \mathfrak p$.) Is this helpful?

Comment: It's easier to just prove it directly from the definition.

Comment: By the way, this is a special case of a more general result: if $f : R_1 \to R_2$ is a ring homomorphism and $\mathfrak p$ is a prime ideal of $R_2$, then $f^{-1}(\mathfrak p)$ is a prime ideal of $R_1$.

Comment: Thank you! I realized that a,b are also elements in  Z[x].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\mathbb Z+I$ is a subring of $\mathbb Z[x]$, $\mathbb Z+I/I$ is a subring of $\mathbb Z[x]/I$, which is known to be an integral domain. The subring of an integral domain is an integral domain.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** consider the (unique) unital ring map $f:\Bbb Z\to \Bbb Z [x] $. What is $f^{-1}(I) $? Kenny Wong's comment will also be useful.

Answer (score 1):

It's simpler than isomorphism theorems. The general fact is this:

> Let $\;f\colon R\longrightarrow S$ be a ring homomorphism. For any prime ideal $\mathfrak q\subset S$, the ideal $\mathfrak p=f^{-1}(\mathfrak q)\subset R$ is prime.

This is very easy to prove $f$ induces an injective ring homomorphism:
$$\bar f\colon R/\mathfrak p\hookrightarrow S/\mathfrak q,$$
which that, since $S/\mathfrak q$ is an integral domain, $R/\mathfrak p$ is.